# SSRS How to limit results to only groups having all values selected in multi-value parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have table issued with columns user.name and item.type grouped by user.name.  I have a multi-value drop-down parameter listing @Item. I want to limit my results to only groups with all selected parameter values.

Dataset1 query is:

```
SELECT 
user.name
, item.type
FROM
 user
INNER JOIN item
  ON user.name = item.user
Where item.type IN (@Type)
```

Then I have a dropdown parameter (@Type) with available values from Dataset 2. Value field and Label field set to type.

Dataset 2 query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
item.type
```

Sample of what the data is:

| Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| John | Sheet |
| John | Blanket |
| John | Soap |
| Jane | Blanket |
| Lisa | Blanket |
| Lisa | Sheet |
| Mike | Sheet |

If Sheet and Blanket are selected in @Item, I would expect to get results for John and Lisa like:

| Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| John | Sheet |
| John | Blanket |
| Lisa | Blanket |
| Lisa | Sheet |

Instead I get:

| Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| John | Sheet |
| John | Blanket |
| Jane | Blanket |
| Lisa | Blanket |
| Lisa | Sheet |
| Mike | Sheet |

I'm getting results for any user with any value selected in the parameter.
I want results for only the users with ALL the values selected in the parameter.

Comment: Where  are you doing this? In your dataset query or in a dataset filter in the report ? Either way show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I edited to add the actual queries and parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain due to the way SSRS injects multi-parameter values into dataset queries, it basically replaces your selection with a comma separated list of values, but includes the quotes around each element.

The idea behind this answer is to count the number of passed in values an compare to the count for each user.

Due to the SSRS multi-value handling, we can't just count how many were passed in so we have two options.

The first is to get a count from the items table where the `type` matches the type parameter, like this...

```
declare @user table ([Name] varchar(20))
declare @item table ([Name] varchar(20), [Type] varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @user 
    VALUES 
        ('John'), ('Jane'), ('Lisa'), ('Mike')

INSERT INTO @item 
    VALUES 
        ('John', 'Sheet'), ('John', 'Blanket'), ('John', 'Soap'),
        ('Jane', 'Blanket'),
        ('Lisa', 'Sheet'), ('Lisa', 'Blanket'),
        ('Mike', 'Sheet')

SELECT 
    [Name], [Type] as Item
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            u.[Name]
            , i.[Type]
            , count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY u.[Name]) as ItemCount
        FROM @user u
            INNER JOIN @item i
                ON u.[Name] = i.[Name]
        WHERE i.[Type] IN (@Type)
    ) a 
    WHERE a.ItemCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Type)) FROM @item WHERE [Type] IN (@Type))
```

The second way is to pass in the count as a parameter, in this case we can just swap out the final `WHERE` for this

```
WHERE a.ItemCount = @iCount
```

We also have to add `iCount` as a dataset parameter and set it's value to

```
=Parameters!Type.Count()
```

Like this...

[image]

Here's the results from the report

[image]

and then with 3 selected

[image]